# v-for inside v-for issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetifyjs3

I would like to ask if someone see the problem in my code.
Everything render ok, no problem with the render, the issue is that every time I click in one panel content all the panel-content of every group with the same index expand or collapse and not only the one that I clicked.
Any idea?? Thanks a lot.

```
<div v-for="(group, i) in groups" :key="i" class="pb-4">
  <p class="text-h5 primary text-center white--text">{{ group.title }}</p>
  <div v-if="group.links">
    <a v-for="(link, u) in group.links" :key="u" :href="link.src" class="black--text"> {{ link.title }}</a>
  </div>
  <v-expansion-panels v-model="activesPanels" multiple accordion dense flat>
    <v-expansion-panel v-for="(item, v) in group.fact" v-show="shouldRender(v)" :key="v">
      <v-expansion-panel-header class="px-0">{{ item.title }}</v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
         <type :fact="item" :models="models" />
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that you are using the same v-model variable `activesPanels` for every group. The `activesPanels` should belong to each group to maintain their opening and closing state individually.

Also, use the unique properties for template keys to avoid errors i.e, **"Duplicate keys detected"**.

Here is the working demo-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
    <div v-for="(group, i) in groups" :key="i">
  <p class="primary text-center white--text">{{ group.title }}</p>
  <div v-if="group.links">
    <a v-for="link in group.links" :key="link.src" :href="link.src" class="black--text"> {{ link.title }}</a>
  </div>
  <v-expansion-panels v-model="group.activesPanels" multiple accordion dense flat>
    <v-expansion-panel v-for="item in group.fact" :key="item.title">
      <v-expansion-panel-header class="pa-0">{{ item.title }}</v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content class="pa-0">
         Hello
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</div>
  </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data () {
      return {
        groups: [
        {
          title: "group1",
          activesPanels: [],
          fact: [
            {
              title: 'fact1'
            }
          ],
          links:[
            {
              src: "https://google.com",
              title: "Hello"
            },
            {
              src: "https://twitter.com",
              title: "Hello"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "group2",
          activesPanels: [],
          fact: [
            {
              title: 'fact2'
            }
          ],
          links:[
            {
              src: "https://www.shorturl.at/",
              title: "Hello"
            },
            {
              src: "https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-map-fields",
              title: "Hello"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      }
      },
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice catch and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using indexes as keys in your v-for loop. The keys need to be unique for every element. By using index you have probably 2 elements with index 0 as a key. Vue cannot keep track of changes in the DOM that way. It is getting even worse if you edit the array and items in the array get another index.

So, you can use a unique value for the key, maybe an id or `link.url` and `item.title` in your code.

See docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key